# Novel with cyborg dolphin & travel to Jupiter

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyborg

There was a dolphin with mechanical equipment attached to it, kinda cyborg like, to communicate with the old scientist.He sends a whale, to Jupiter, in a huge water tank. I believe he is killed by the whale in the tank. There was a younger scientist, maybe a relative of the older scientist, that was against the experiments. Jovian cyborg dolphins, stays in my mind. The battle with the whale reminded me of the Moby Dick conflict.

I read it, overseas, in 1985.

Comment: Sounds like a whale of a tale...

Comment: Here are some lists that may help: [Science fiction on, under, about the sea](http://www.alisonsinclair.ca/novels/blueheart/sfsea/); 

[Under the sea](http://www.magicdragon.com/UltimateSF/thisthat.html#undersea); 

[Cetacean Fiction Bibliography](http://www.helsinki.fi/~lauhakan/whale/literature/fiction.html)

Comment: Well, you may be confusing multiple tales.  David Brin has a whole series in which Dophins are main characters.  They use cyberntic attachments to fly star ships.  In one in particular, they crash on a water world (not Jupiter) and have to try to repair their ship.  One of them turns out to have some killer whale DNA and essentially goes on a crazy killing spree.  Doesn't sound like your story, but lots of similarities.  Maybe in the fog of the past you've conflated several different stories in your mind?

Answer (score 4):

[image: A Deeper Sea by Alexander Jablokov - Book Cover - reduced]

[**A Deeper Sea**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2126) by Alexander Jablokov

According to the [blurb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0380717093):

> In the year 2015, a dolphin researcher with dubious motives removes
> the barriers impeding human/delphine communications and transforms the
> ocean-dwelling creatures into cybernetic weapons of destruction.

Other details from a [review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1254495.A_Deeper_Sea):

> Five years later, the world's superpowers are at war - and **Stasov
> [the research scientist] has transformed his dolphins into deadly
> armored cyborgs** designed to wreak havoc on the ocean-going vessels of
> his nation's enemies.
>
> But his control over the events he has set in motion is rapidly
> eroding. For the dolphins have their own agenda that transcends the
> petty hostilities and self-serving greed of human beings.

[tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpaceWhale) briefly mentions the whale and its mission:

> The novel involves **a whale being turned into a spacefaring cyborg** to
> fulfill a religious prophecy of the dolphins, with whom man has
> learned to communicate.

Another [reviewer](http://www.laphamsquarterly.org/roundtable/roundtable/the-fantastical-allure-of-the-space-whale.php) sheds a little more light:

> A tormented Russian scientist, who drafted dolphins as soldiers in
> human wars, becomes convinced that a whale and a dolphin are the
> pre-ordained interpreters who will allow humans to communicate with
> alien intelligence living near Jupiter.
>
> **By creating a cyborg “whale” to survive in Jupiter’s atmosphere**, the scientist accomplishes his feat only by deceiving the robotic whale
> into believing that he is still swimming in an Earthly sea.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds close to the novel [Cachalot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cachalot_%28novel%29) by Alan Dean Foster. From the wikipedia article:

> Cachalot is an ocean planet where humans have begun building floating
>   cities. It is also the same planet where all of Earth’s cetaceans were
>   transplanted six hundred years ago after the Covenant of Peace was
>   enacted with all intelligence-enhanced ocean dwellers. Five of these
>   cities have been destroyed when a middle-aged scientist and her
>   late-teen daughter are dispatched to the planet to discover the source
>   of the attacks.